# WebMvc test with ControllerAdvice that contains autowired properties

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, java-8, controller, autowired

Considering the code bellow as part of a SpringBoot application with latest versions, in some projects the test results is a failure to start application because it failed to inject the ErrorMessages into the ControllerAdvice. But for some reason in other projects this code passes. I don't have any diferences in configuration, gradle-build, or annotations so not entirely sure if I found a bug or not.
Is there any way to influence the ErrorMessages to be read and injected on a @WebMvcTest ?

Controller on Controller folder

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "Some Service", tags = "Some Service")
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets something")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = ErrorResponse.class) })
    @GetMapping(value = "/something", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> getSomething(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomOAuth2Authentication authentication,
    ) throws ApiException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(someService.get());
    }
}
```

Controller advice on Exception folder

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMessages errorMessages;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse handler(HttpServletRequest request, final Throwable ex) 
    {
        log.error("Unexpected error", ex);
        return new ErrorResponseBuilder().with(it -> {
            it.status = ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION;
            it.error = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            it.exception = ex.getClass().getName();
            it.messages = Collections.singletonList(errorMessages.internalServerException);
            it.path = request.getRequestURI();
        }).build();
    }
}
```

errorMessages on Exception folder (reads from Spring Cloud)

```
@Component
public class ErrorMessages {

    @Value("${"+ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION +"}")
    public String internalServerException;

}
```

errorCodes on Exception Folder

```
public class ErrorCodes {
    private ErrorCodes() {}

    public static final String INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION = "3031";
}
```

TestClass on Test folder

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ErrorMessages.class, 
GlobalExceptionHandler.class})
public class SomeControllerTest {

    private String SERVICE_URL = "/some";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws ApiException {

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    ErrorMessages errorMessages;

    @MockBean
    private SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private SomeController someController;

    @Test
    @WithMockCustomUser()
    public void getCheckout_Exception() throws Exception {
        ApiException e = new ApiException("code123", "message123");
        when(someService.get(anyString(), anyInt())).thenThrow(e);
        mockMvc.perform(get(SERVICE_URL))
            .andExpect( status().is( equalTo( 
               HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())))
            .andExpect( content().string(containsString(e.getClass().getName())))
            .andExpect( content().string(containsString(e.getCode())))
            .andExpect( content().string(containsString(e.getMessage())))
            .andExpect( content().string(containsString(errorMessages.transformingException)));
    }
}
```

Error is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'globalExceptionHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'errorMessages'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.comp.proj.service.something.exception.ErrorMessages' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
```

Comment: You should also post the stack trace/ exception encountered while starting the application.

Comment: added stack-trace but it doesn't tell anything other than the errorMessage is not on the context and therefore could not be injected

Comment: Did you figure this out?. If so can you share as I'm running at the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can try importing your exception handler in your test class:

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "Some Service", tags = "Some Service")
@Import(GlobalExceptionHandler.class)  // EXCEPTION HANDLER CLASS
public class SomeController {
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of error is that you are using @WebMvcTest.
This annotation loads only beans which are annotated with @Controller, @RestController, @ControllerAdvice. It skips all other spring beans annotated(e.f @component, @service and others)

I am guessing that your bean "ErrorMessage" is annotated with one of these excluded annotations and this you are getting below error:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'errorMessages'

Solution: You can use @SpringBootTest instead of @WebMvcTest. The only downside is that springboottest will load all the spring beans and thus would be slower.

If you have any option not to use "ErrorMessage" dependency then this error will itself go away.
Note: ErrorMessage seems to be data and that should anyway not be autowired as spring bean are singleton by default and thus can cause other functional issues.